# java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Long error

Tags: java

```
public class DBqueries {

   public static FirebaseFirestore firebaseFirestore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
    public static List<CategoryModel> categoryModelList = new ArrayList<>();
    public static List<HomePageModel> homePageModelList = new ArrayList<>();

    public static void loadCategories(final CategoryAdapter categoryAdapter, final Context context){



        firebaseFirestore.collection("CATEGORIES").orderBy("index").get()
                .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()){
                            for (QueryDocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot : task.getResult()){
                                categoryModelList.add(new CategoryModel(documentSnapshot.get("icon").toString(),documentSnapshot.get("categoryName").toString()));
                            }
                            categoryAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        }else {
                            String error = task.getException().getMessage();
                            Toast.makeText(context, error, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }
                });
    }

    public static void loadFragmentData(final HomePageAdapter adapter, final Context context){
        firebaseFirestore.collection("CATEGORIES")
                .document("HOME")
                .collection("TOP_DEALS").orderBy("index").get()
                .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()){
                            for (QueryDocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot : task.getResult()){

                                if ((long)documentSnapshot.get("view_type") == 0){
                                    List<SliderModel> sliderModelList = new ArrayList<>();
                                    long no_of_banners = (long) documentSnapshot.get("no_of_banners");
                                    for (long x = 1;x < no_of_banners + 1;x++){
                                        sliderModelList.add(new SliderModel((String) documentSnapshot.get("banner_"+x)
                                                ,documentSnapshot.get("banner_"+x+"_background").toString()));
                                    }
                                    homePageModelList.add(new HomePageModel(0,sliderModelList));

                                }else if ((long)documentSnapshot.get("view_type") == 1){
                                    homePageModelList.add(new HomePageModel(1, (String) documentSnapshot.get("strip_ad_banner"),
                                            documentSnapshot.get("background").toString()));

                                }else if ((long)documentSnapshot.get("view_type") == 2){

                                    List<WishlistModel> viewAllProductList = new ArrayList<>();
                                    List<HorizontalProductScrollModel> horizontalProductScrollModelList = new ArrayList<>();
                                    long no_of_products = (long) documentSnapshot.get("no_of_products");
                                    for (long x = 1;x < no_of_products + 1;x++){
                                        horizontalProductScrollModelList.add(new HorizontalProductScrollModel(documentSnapshot.get("product_ID_"+x).toString()
                                                ,documentSnapshot.get("product_image_"+x).toString()
                                                ,documentSnapshot.get("product_title_"+x).toString()
                                                ,documentSnapshot.get("product_subtitle_"+x).toString()
                                                ,documentSnapshot.get("product_price_"+x).toString()));


                                        viewAllProductList.add(new WishlistModel(documentSnapshot.get("product_image_"+x).toString()
                                                ,documentSnapshot.get("product_full_title_"+x).toString()
                                                ,(long)documentSnapshot.get("free_coupons_"+x)
                                                ,documentSnapshot.get("average_rating_"+x).toString()
                                                ,(long)documentSnapshot.get("total_ratings_"+x)
                                                ,documentSnapshot.get("product_price_"+x).toString()
                                                ,documentSnapshot.get("cutted_price_"+x).toString()
                                                ,(boolean)documentSnapshot.get("COD_"+x)));

                                    }
                                    homePageModelList.add(new HomePageModel(2,documentSnapshot.get("layout_title").toString()
                                            ,documentSnapshot.get("layout_background").toString(),
                                            horizontalProductScrollModelList,viewAllProductList));


                                }else if ((long)documentSnapshot.get("view_type") == 3){
                                    List<HorizontalProductScrollModel> gridLayoutModelList = new ArrayList<>();
                                    long no_of_products = (long) documentSnapshot.get("no_of_products");
                                    for (long x = 1;x < no_of_products + 1;x++){
                                        gridLayoutModelList.add(new HorizontalProductScrollModel(documentSnapshot.get("product_ID_"+x).toString()
                                                ,documentSnapshot.get("product_image_"+x).toString()
                                                ,documentSnapshot.get("product_title_"+x).toString()
                                                ,documentSnapshot.get("product_subtitle_"+x).toString()
                                                ,documentSnapshot.get("product_price_"+x).toString()));
                                    }
                                    homePageModelList.add(new HomePageModel(3,documentSnapshot.get("layout_title").toString()
                                            ,documentSnapshot.get("layout_background").toString(),
                                            gridLayoutModelList));

                                }
                            }
                            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        }else {
                            String error = task.getException().getMessage();
                            Toast.makeText(context, error, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }
                });
    }
}
```

When I run the code I get this exception:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Long
```

Is there any other way to convert the result?

Comment: Have you read the error message? Do you understand what a ClassCastException is? Have you read the javadoc of this exception? Have you read the line number that comes with the exception and indicates the precise line in your code that throws this exception?

Comment: You can always check using **instance of** before casting.

Comment: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Long
        at com.shoppound.shoppound.DBqueries$2.onComplete(DBqueries.java:54)

Comment: @DEKHOAURSIKHO so, what is the line 54 of DBqueries.java

Comment: `@DEKHOAURSIKHO, please add your whole error stack trace` in your question, not here

Comment: Read the API for `DocumentSnapshot` as well. There are various getter methods, no need for you to cast anything explicitly (if thats where the ClassCastException is coming from).

Comment: this is line 54. if ((long)documentSnapshot.get("view_type") == 0)

Comment: OK. So at that line, you get the property "view_type" from the document snapshot, and cast it to long. And that fails with the error "ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Long". So that means that the property is actually a String, not a Long, and you can't cast a String to Long. So, acknowledge that fact, and cast the result to a String instead of casting it to a Long. Then do what you need to do with that String. If this is **supposed** to contain a Long and not a String, then maybe your database contains junk data that needs to be cleaned up, too.

Comment: i am migrating to android x.

Comment: Casting is not conversion. It isn't magic. If you want a `long` from a `String` you need `Long.valueOf(String)`, not a typecast.

Answer (score 0):

Use the proper API method provided by the `QueryDocumentSnapshot` (inherited from `DocumentSnapshot`) instead of your (incorrect) manually casting of your result to the proper type.

e.g:
https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/firebase/firestore/DocumentSnapshot.html#getLong(java.lang.String)